# Drupal: 3 blocks (authenticated users can only edit 2 of 3 !?)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm developing a website in Drupal 6.

I've 3 blocks (I use as footers), I've created the first 2 time ago and recently I've added a new one.

As root I can, of course, edit all of them, but authorized users can only edit 2 of them. I dunno how to change preferences for the third block.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check that the block was created in an *input format* accessible to those users. If they do not have access to the input format, you will need to grant them access to that format or change the format on the block to a more generally accessible one.

Comment: great, this was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you look in the permissions page in /admin/user/permissions/ and check all necessary boxes for the authorized user?

Comment: Yes and I didn't found any specific one for blocks, and more important, for each single block. Because the other 2 blocks are editable, only the third one is not...

Comment: in your question can you state what version of drupal are you using?